# Java android TimePickerDialog change tittle display time

Tags: java, android, time-format

I created a `TimePickerDialog` and on top on my dialog I see a time which I set. I see HH:mm AM but I don't want to see a "AM". I don't set title and I don't know how I can override this title. How I can do this?

```
 public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{

        private TimePickerDialog timepic;
        private Calendar dateLimit;


        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

            Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            if (flag == 0) {
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                startDate = calendar.getTime();
//                if (endDate.getTime() < startDate.getTime())
//                    tvEndDate.setText("");
//                tvStartDate.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(startDate));
            } else if (flag == 1) {
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                endDate = calendar.getTime();
//                if (endDate.getTime() >= startDate.getTime())
//                    tvEndDate.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(endDate));
//                else
//                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Data końcowa musi być większa od daty początkowej", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            if (flag == 0) {
                c = DateToCalendar(startDate);
            } else if (flag == 1) {
                c = DateToCalendar(endDate);
            }
            timepic = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true);
            return timepic;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

TimePickerDialog is subclass of AlertDialog. It means you can use `setTitle(CharSequence text)` method directly when `onTimeSet` is called.